# REST Tomcat Root URL web.xml @Path

Tags: java, hibernate, rest, maven, tomcat

Ok i have a problem with my REST Application, it worked well until i started to change the URL/Context of the App..

i could access my service under https://url/RESTservice/rest/restmethod, but i wanted to change this to https://url/rest/restmethod, i did a few changes but reverting these doesnt seem to fix the issue.

starting with the ServiceMain.java...

```
@Path("/")
public class ServiceMain extends Application
```

following the web.xml file...

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>bob-rest-service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>de.bob</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.classnames</param-name>
        <param-value>org.glassfish.jersey.filter.LoggingFilter;org.glassfish.jersey.moxy.json.MoxyFeature;org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.MultiPartFeature</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>bob-rest-service</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

The maven pom.xml...

```
<build>
    <finalName>RESTservice</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

and the last thing is the Tomcat Modules View on Eclipse which directs to "/RESTservice" and in the Project->Properties-> Web Project Settings->Context root: "RESTservice".

This is my actual setup, the problem now lays in that i get HTTP 404 when i call my rest methods, they were working fine on friday until i started to change the Path.

Error Log:

```
Jun 27, 2016 9:57:25 AM org.glassfish.jersey.filter.LoggingFilter log
INFORMATION: 14 * Server has received a request on thread http-bio-443-exec-8
14 > POST https://bob.de/RESTservice/rest/login
14 > accept-encoding: gzip,deflate
14 > connection: Keep-Alive
14 > content-length: 127
14 > content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
14 > host: bob.de
14 > user-agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.2 (Java/1.8.0_91)

Jun 27, 2016 9:57:25 AM org.glassfish.jersey.filter.LoggingFilter log
INFORMATION: 14 * Server responded with a response on thread http-bio-443-exec-8
14 < 404
```

EDIT: What i am wondering is that when i had similar problems that i had that ClassNotFound Exception and the Hibernate Queries where not shown, once it worked the hibernate stuff was shown. So may i have a problem with Hibernate?

EDIT2: It seems that the resources are not loaded, because of lacking experience, i am having heavy problems now.

Comment: Why do you have the `ServiceMain` class at all? You don't need it.

Comment: i followed a Tutorial where it was like that, whats the better approach?

Comment: You don't need it because you have all your configuration in the web.xml. And adding `@Path` on top of it messes with all the other endpoints, as it is picked up in the package scanning, and added as a root resource

Comment: So should i remove all the @Path Annotations of the Methods?

Comment: You should just delete that entire class

Comment: FYI, i have my JSON Methods inside of that class, i removed "extends Application" as it seems like you are right and it will run without it too.

I took a look at this site http://howtodoinjava.com/jersey/jersey-2-hello-world-application-tutorial/

or do you have a better starting point for me, i developed my rest stuff since a few weeks and never had this problem so far.

Comment: Are you saying that nothing works? Or just the stripped down URL?\

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115729/discussion-between-kaya-and-peeskillet).

Answer (score 0):

General URL we use for application is https://Ip:Port/ApplicationName.
In your case you uses below urlwhich working fine 
https://url/RESTservice/rest/restmethod.
In this Url, RESTservice is application name.
Now you want to change to other Url which missing the application name in Url.
Add application name in Url so it will work fine

Comment: i reverted all and it still doesnt works as before :\

Answer (score 0):

Created a new Workspace for testing purposes, it works instantly, WTH eclipse!

EDIT: i also now got the URL as i wanted without the APP name, therefore just Doubleclick on your tomcat instance under Servers Browser -> Click on Modules -> Select your App -> Edit -> remove the URL at the Path: